# C++ problems to read binary files

Tags: binary

Goodmorning, I'm writing a c++ code for write and read binary files. I tried with a simple case as follow:

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
    
 
void writeb(string text1)
{
 ofstream outfile("binary.txt", ios::binary);
 if (outfile.is_open())
 { 
 int strlen1=text1.length();
 outfile.write((char*) &strlen1, sizeof(int));
 outfile.write((char*) &text1, strlen1 );  
    outfile.close();
 }
 
 ifstream infile("binary.txt", ios::binary);
 string text2;
 if (infile.is_open())
 { 
 int strlen2=0;
 infile.read((char*) &strlen2, sizeof(int));
 cout << "check " << strlen2 <<" ";
 text2.resize(strlen2);
 infile.read((char*)(&text2), strlen2);
    cout << text2 << endl;
    infile.close(); 
 }
}
void readb()
{
 ifstream infile("binary.txt", ios::binary);
 string text3;
 if (infile.is_open())
 { 
 int strlen3=0;
 infile.read((char*) &strlen3, sizeof(int));
 cout << "read " << strlen3 <<" ";
 infile.read((char*)(&text3), strlen3);
    cout << text3 << endl;
    infile.close();  
 }
}


int main()
{   
    string text = "Hello! How are you?";
 writeb(text);
 readb();   
}
```

where there are two functions: one to write the binary file with a check of what is written and one to read the binary file only.

Unfortunately the reader function doesn't work as expected.

Infact I obtain the following output:

```html
check 19 Hello! How are you?
read 19 ©zs Ïs ow are you?
```

In particular seems that the reader function is not able to read the binary file correctly, while the check reader in the writer function works correctly. I could not understand where the mistake is.
Can someone help me to solve this problem? Or can someone suggest to me other solutions to write and read binary files in separated functions? 
Thank you very much
Best regards
DS

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is your typecast `(char*) &text1`. You are typecasting a string object to a char pointer.

What you should do is use `text1.c_str()` this will give you the const char* to the actual data contained in string object.

#### Edit:

**You also forgot to resize the string in your readb function.**

I would probably just use a char* to read and write to the binary because what your code is doing now is dumping the contents of string object as binary into your file.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the answer. 
I hope I understand your suggestion correctly and I corrected the code with:

```html
infile.read((char*)(text3.c_str()), strlen3 ); 
cout << text3 << endl;
```

or

```html
infile.read((char*)(&text3), strlen3 );
cout << text3.c_str() << endl;
```

Unfortunately the code continue to give me a wrong output.

thank you very much
Best regards 
DS